# Ansible Azure Modules

Tags: python-2.7, azure, ansible, ansi

I'm trying to use the Azure modules for Ansible on Red Hat. I followed the official documentation for Ansible installation on site. While executing the Ansible playbook I ran into below problem.

```
Failed to import the required Python library (ansible[azure] (azure >= 2.0.0)) on azure-redhat Python /usr/bin/python2.
```

I removed Ansible and pip packages and reinstalled them. The problem still persists. Can anyone help me with it?

- Ansible version = 2.8.4
- python2.7
- Redhat 7.

Comment: Can you give a pointer to the documentation you followed. I want to see how (sources+which command+which user) you installed ansible, pip and azure modules.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/ansible-install-configure ?

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/scenario_guides/guide_azure.html
I followed the above link and executed pip install 'ansible[azure]'

Answer (score 1):

As the comment points it out, you could follow [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/ansible-install-configure?) to install Ansible on an Azure Linux virtual machine.

- Install the required packages for the Azure Python SDK modules.

  `sudo yum check-update; sudo yum install -y gcc libffi-devel python-devel openssl-devel epel-release
  sudo yum install -y python-pip python-wheel`
- Install the required packages for the Azure Python SDK modules.

  `sudo pip install ansible[azure]`

This works for me on RedHat 7.4 azure VM.
[image]

Comment: It's: `pip install 'ansible[azure]'`

Comment: Not working to me